# GetGroups vs GetAuthorizationGroups

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, active-directory

When I am using GetGroups instead of GetAuthorizationGroup, it results fine but the later one retrieve none even if group exists for the given user. The code I have used as below:

```
string userName = "userid";

PrincipalContext yourDomain = CurrentPrincipalContext;
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(yourDomain, userName);
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetGroups();//user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
List<GroupPrincipal> result = groups.Select(x => (GroupPrincipal)x).ToList();
return result.Select(g => g.Name).ToList();
```

I can use GetGroups but the GetGroups method retrieve data in localhost but fetching none when pushed it into IIS 6.0 and thus I have to stick on GetAuthorizationGroups.

Please help me out....

Answer (score 0):

GetAuthorizationGroups fails due to an obsolete SID in ActiveDirectory. Because GetAuthorizationGroups works recursively it could be a top-level SID or one attached to a top-level group. I'm including a link to hopefully help.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9dd81553-3539-4281-addd-3eb75e6e4d5d/getauthorizationgroups-fails-with-nomatchingprincipalexception?forum=csharpgeneral

NOTE: I've also been told that GetAuthorizationGroups caches the results somewhere for some length of time and isnt able to be cleared manually. Because of this I've had to write code to spelunk the Groups.